# Rapid SVN fails suddenly with Error

Tags: svn

My svn server does not work suddenly. It fails with the following error:

`rapidsvn: /usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.26: version 'GNUTLS_2_12' not found (required by /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27)`

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit.

Answer (score 0):

Is GnuTLS installed?  Was it recently upgraded or removed?
`dkpg-query --list gnutls`
It may be interesting to check `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see if someone else did this